# inserting multiple records in mySQL data base from react-native and node-js

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have an invoice app where you can add many products to the same invoice (bill)
in mySQL i have a products table where i want to add every single product i have added in the invoice.
i have managed to save all the products inside an array.

```
Array [
  Object {
    "amt": "1",
    "desc": "Item1",
    "index": 0,
    "qty": "1",
  },
  Object {
    "amt": "2",
    "desc": "Item2",
    "index": 1,
    "qty": "2",
  },
  Object {
    "amt": "3",
    "desc": "Item3",
    "index": 2,
    "qty": "3",
  },
  Object {
    "amt": "4",
    "desc": "Item4",
    "index": 3,
    "qty": "4",
  },
]
```

on button click i want to send an api that inserts the data inside the table in mySQL.

```
 app.post("/addproducts", (req, res) => {
      let product= req.body;
      var sql =
        "INSERT INTO products (amt, desc, qty, invoiceId) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);";
      mysqlConnection.query(
        sql,
        [
          product.invoiceId,
          product.amt,
          product.desc,
          product.qty,
        ],
        (err, rows, fields) => {
          if (!err) {
            res.send(rows);
            });
          } else {
            res.send(err);
          }
        }
      );
    });
```

how can i fix my api to go through the array one by one and insert all the products inside the table

PS: invoice id is the foreign key inside the product table (don't mind it)

```
axios
      .post("http://192.168.0.117:3000/addInvoice", {
        address: address,
        invoiceId: invoiceId,
        amt: invoicenumber,
        desc: desc,
        qty: qty,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        alert("Invoice sent to customer!");
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
  };
```

this is the post api from front-end

How can i map through the data array (that i showed at the beginning) and send the objects one by one?

Comment: Well a loop of some sort would seem a likely start place

Answer (score 1):

Bulk inserts are possible by using nested array.

In your case data should look like :

```
var sql =
    "INSERT INTO products (amt, desc, qty, invoiceId) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);";

let values = [
  ['1', 'Item1', '0', '1'],
  ['2', 'Item2', '1', '2'],
  ...
]

mysqlConnection.query(sql, values, ...)
```

(Care about field order)

Comment: yes but how can i send the data from front-end to back end

Comment: can you help me with it?

Comment: This edit is adding another non related question, you should add it in another thread since it doesn't have any relation with inserting multiples records to MySQL